# String range alternative in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, .net-2.0, substring

Is there any function similar to [string range](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/tutorial/Tcl17.html) in `vb.net 2.0` ??

What I am try to achieve here is to extract some text from a string with unknown length.

eg.

```
given string = text text text mytext1 text text text text mytext2 text text text text
expected string = mytext1 text text text text mytext2
```

So I have the indexes for `"mytext1"` and `"mytext2"`. I am looking for a way to get the text that wrapped in between those two strings or indexes.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, what’s wrong with [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx)? It works on indices so if you want to find text delimited by two words, you first need to find their respective indices using [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx).

```
Dim from = given.IndexOf("mytext1")
Dim [to] = given.IndexOf("mytext2")
Dim result = given.Substring(from, [to] - from + "mytext2".Length)
```

(Note that `To` is a reserved word so I need to put the identifier in square braces … or use another identifier. ;-))

Comment: I think he was just asking for the name of the function in VB.Net. And yes the function he is looking for is `Substring`

Comment: @squelos Possible although the question is *tagged* `[substring]` so I thought the OP was aware of the method.

Comment: @squelos I know about the **substring** function.. i was just looking is there any alternative function to the one i mentioned in question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your End Index is at the end of "myText2" then you can do this...

```
Dim strExpectedString = Mid(strGivenString, intStartIndex, (intEndIndex - intStartIndex))
```

Otherwise just add the length of "myText2" to intEndIndex.

Comment: No advantage at all in using `Mid` over `Substring`. `Mid` exists only for backwards compatibility reasons and doesn’t work on all platforms (Compact Framework …).